# concurrent reading and writing image files (asp.net, but applies to most web languages)

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, io, webcam

I have a .jpg file which represents the current image from a webcam. User's will be downloading this file at an interval of once a second.  Because there could be dozens of users reading it, this could be dozens of times a second (which is normal for any web server).

Problem is, this image is updated by a 3rd party application also once a second which "spiders" my local networks webcam portal image.  This is so we can build our webcams into our current administration panel.

The problem I am already finding is ASP.net sometimes gets an error it can not access the file because it is open for write permissions by the bot.  Likewise, the bot can not access it because IIS is feeding it to the user.

The bot uses io.streamwriter to save the data to the file, and my script uses Response.WriteFile to send the file to the script. (I need to use an actual ASP.net page with a JPG content-type that feeds the file to make sure only users with a active session can view the JPG).

My question is what is the best practices for this?  I know why it's happening but what is the best resolution for this?  Would storing as a BLOB in a database maybe be smarter since databases are created for concurrent read/writing already? Is there an easier way of doing this with a file I have not thought of yet?

Thanks in advance,

Anthony Greco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a BLOB will work if the readers use SNAPSHOT isolation model (SQL Server 2005 and up). See [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) for how to stream an image from a BLOB, and see [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx) for a lecture on SNAPSHOT.

But using a BLOB may be overkill, you could get away with something much simpler. For instance, if you only have one ASP.Net process, then you could have a global [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) variable for the current file name. The writer writes the JPG into a *new* file, and then updates the global 'current' file name with an [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7etff8w.aspx) operation (it has to be Compare because a newer writer might actually finish faster, outrun a previous writer, and you want to preserve the latest update). There are still some issues left to solve (find out the file name at startup, clean up old files etc) but they are all fairly ease to solve.

If you have a farm of servers, or multiple ASP.Net processes serving the site, then things could get complicated. I would still do a rotating file name and do a try-and-error approach (try to respond with newest file, fall back to previous older one if conflict is detected).

Comment: Thank you. It will be some time till i can test this out but both answers seem to be a better option than what I am currently doing. I wasn't sure if using two files was actually efficient enough, but if it's the best option mine as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could get the bot to write the data to a different filename and then do a delete and rename to the filename being served by ASP.Net.  This should reduce the file lock time down to the time for a delete and rename to occur. To clarify:

1. ASP.Net serving image from "webcam.jpg"
2. bot writes image data to "temp.jpg"
3. when last image byte written, bot deletes "webcam.jpg" and renames "temp.jpg" to "webcam.jpg"

ASP.Net should check "webcam.jpg" exists, if not wait 10ms (or suitable small increment) and check again.

Comment: This will minimize time I guess, but I can see the issue still eventually happening every so often if i am getting 100's of requests a second.  I will give it a try though